# Debug Swift crash EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, crash

I just downloaded a crash that happened and I am not sure how I could get more details as to what happened. All I can see is that crash happened inside of a `Operation Queue`, all I can see is that it happened inside of `SyncToServer.sync(object:)` method call and that it happened inside of a block.

I suspect that it could happen in this part of code:

```
self.queue.async {
    if success {
        self.syncObjects.remove(at: index)
        self.saveState()
    } else {
        self.syncIndex += 1
    }
    self.syncing = false
    self.sync()
}
```

I am also attaching the crash report below.

[image: Crash report]

Comment: Could  it be that sometimes `index` is out of bounds, and so  `remove(at: index)` crashes?

Comment: I agree, from the code I inspected I can only see the syncObjects.remove(at:) crashing, in Objective C I would get a better report of the crash I believe, where it would say it was out of bounds...here it just says `#0 (null) in closure #1 in closure #1 in SyncToServer.sync(object:) ()`